# want to retrieve data from Firebase database in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I am trying to display a list of post from the Firebase database in react but it displays nothing, I do not know where I made mistake.i am using  firebase version 9. i think i made a mistake in useEffect section**
note: it displays post list from the given array but i want to display from the database

here is my app.js code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {db} from "./firebase";
import Post from "./Post";

import { getFirestore, collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

function App() {
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([
    //  {
    //    username: "golam Rabbani",
    //    userUrl: "https://www.logogenie.net/images/articles/instagram-logo2.jpg",
    //    usercaption: "this is really cool caption",
    //  },
    //  {
    //    username: "golam Rabbani",
    //    userUrl: "https://www.logogenie.net/images/articles/instagram-logo2.jpg",
    //    usercaption: "this is really cool caption",
    //  },
  ]);

  
   useEffect(() => {
   
    async function getPost(db) {
      const postCol = collection(db, 'posts');
      const postSnapshot = await getDocs(postCol);
      const postList = postSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      return postList;
    }



   }, []); //[post]for every single time post change code will run again,for[] run only once
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {/* header */}
      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          alt="headerimg"
          className="app__header__img"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Instagram_logo.svg/1200px-Instagram_logo.svg.png"
        />
      </div>
      <h1>
        this is for learning purpose and many thing that i belive and i will
        continue so
      </h1>

      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          username={post.username}
          userUrl={post.userUrl}
          caption={post.caption}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hi @Golam rabbani Rocky, could you please try to remove the `db` inside the `getPost`. It shoud be `getPost()` instead of `getPost(db)` as it is already declared on your import.

Comment: i applied what you have said but still unable to retrieve data from firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working code:

```
function App() {
  const [posts, setposts] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'posts'))
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setposts(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        data: doc.data()
      })))
    })
   }, []); //[post]for every single time post change code will run again,for[] run only once
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {/* header */}
      <div className="app__header">
        <img
          alt="headerimg"
          className="app__header__img"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2a/Instagram_logo.svg/1200px-Instagram_logo.svg.png"
        />
      </div>
      <h1>
        this is for learning purpose and many thing that i belive and i will
        continue so
      </h1>

      {posts.map((post) => (
        <Post
          username={post.username}
          userUrl={post.userUrl}
          caption={post.caption}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you have a use-case and still need to use `async function` inside the `useEffect()`. Use the code below:

```
   useEffect(() => {
   
    const getPost = async () => {
      const postCol = collection(db, 'users');
      const postSnapshot = await getDocs(postCol);
      const postList = postSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
      // Set the result to the useState.
      setposts(postList);
    }
    // Call the async function.
    getPost()
      .catch(console.error);

   }, []); //[post]for every single time post change code will run again,for[] run only once
```

You may want to check this [blog](https://devtrium.com/posts/async-functions-useeffect) for examples using `async` inside the `useEffect`.

Comment: thank you much, I have done this but I forgot to  call the function